# Add more token to your liquidity pool on Uniswap without adding ETH

Tags: tokens, uniswap, liquidity-provider

If you start with a small supply of your token to Uniswap and over time want to add more tokens to the supply without adding ETH, is this possible?

I know you could distribute to token holders say as airdrops, but then any sold tokens to the pool is also removing ETH.

The thought is at the beginning of a token project, being able to correctly and carefully add supply to the market while the price is moving up to match the right amount of front end inflation and get your total supply out to the market over time.

Comment: Of course, this is possible in Uniswap v2 and Uniswap v3. They are both agnostic to what ERC-20 pairs you use. [Read the docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/).

Comment: I'm reviewing docs in 'Providing Liquidity'. This is setting up the contract parameters before adding liquidity isn't it? What if you loaded on the initial liquidity directly on uniswap and v3 automatically created the contract for you. Is there the ability to add more token directly on uniswap without ETH or do you need to create a new contract and run the mintNewPosition()? Thanks.